# DDD Dynamic Service Injection

Tags: c#, service, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, inversion-of-control

I am currently building a DDD application that validates loans.  Each loan has various validation checks that must be performed before a loan is approved.  The validation checks vary a fair amount from loan to loan and most require external (infrastructure) services to complete.

So given that, we decided the best way to implement these checks would be to create a config file for each loan type, which would list the specific rules and the respective validator service that could perform the rule check.  In addition, some rules require specific parameters to be passed along.  Such as for a credit score check, there would be a threshold value (must be over 600 for example).  For that we think we should just pass a dictionary object of strings, called validation criteria.  Unless someone has a more elegant way to do this?

Right now my Loan entity has a validate method which accepts a list of rules to check against.  My question is, what's the best way to resolve the service references from the config file at runtime?  Pass a service factory to the Validate() method, which accepts a string validator name?

I am using Unity for DI in the rest of the app, but can't figure out the best way to do this dynamically at runtime.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you determine the type of a loan? Is every type of loan a sub type of `Loan`, does `Loan` have a `Type` property of enum type `LoanType`, or who do you define a loan type?

Comment: The loan type is determined by the lender.  The lender sets the rules for a loan to be approved.  Our company is the middle man which does the validation for loans that come in.  So we want a system that we can easily work with new lenders and their specific list of rules to enforce.  Loan type was really the wrong term to use here.  I apologize, but I was just trying to simplify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im my opinion the runtime creation of validation rules is significant part of your domain. So I would recommend to extract the validation from a "validate()" method (this is good for simple validation rules) and add to some sort of "validation rule builder".

Such class should be first class citizen to make that concept explicit. It would would dynamically build a validator chain or something similar based on the current context (loan type, user type etc) and config settings. The validator chain would comprise individual validator objects that could be easily injected from DIC and also such objects can be easily unit tested in separation.

To sum it up - the validation chain builder knows "what" to validate (which individual validation objects need to be applied based on context) and the validator object would know how (the validation details that need be applied). I guess that is also nice way how to split the responsibilities.